# Why does refrigerant condense in oil?

Tags: vapor-pressure

In a closed system (think of a typical AC system) why does refrigerant tend to condense and settle in oil?

I’ve heard that the vapor pressure of the oil is very low so that causes a pressure difference which draws the refrigerant into the oil and causes it to condense. The refrigerant is more dense than oil so it will tend to settle below the oil. Once enough refrigerant condenses in the oil the vapor pressure will be equal to the vapor pressure in the system so there will no longer be any flow.

I work in HVAC and I’m not satisfied with just knowing the practical side of this effect (refrigerant migration), I’d like to know how exactly this works. Maybe I lack a deep enough understanding of vapor pressure.

I understand that refrigerant and oil have different vapor pressures but I have trouble understanding how this causes flow since the entire system is under the same amount of pressure. Also why does it tend to condense into a liquid? How much refrigerant must condense and settle below the refrigerant before pressures are equalized?

Formulas are appreciated.